# nginx can't see/use my external drive?

Tags: nginx, configuration, permissions

I recently moved all my side projects to an external drive I carry around,  and noticed nginx on Ubuntu keeps choking with my idea of using the drive as a document root, giving me `Permission Denied` errors every single time.

It is NTFS formatted and doing a chmod -R 777 /media/MyExternalDrive hasn't solved anything; I mention this because I suspect it is somehow related.

What is going on and how do I fix this?